# Perimeter of union of N rectangles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I want to know the efficient way to solve this problem:

> Given N rectangles that given a top-left and bottom-right corner, please find the perimeter of union of N rectangles.

I only have `O(N^2)` algorithm and it's too slow, so please find more efficient algorithm. 

You can assume that coordinate value is positive integer and less than 100000.

EDIT:
For example, in this case, the perimeter is 30. 

[image: Example]

An O(n^2) algorithm:

```
for x=0 to maxx
   for i=0 to N
      if lowx[i] = x
         for j=lowy[i] to highy[i]
            d[j]++
            if d[j] = 1 then ret++
      if highy[i] = x
         for j=lowy[i] to highy[i]
            d[j]--
            if d[j] = 0 then ret++
   for y=0 to maxy
      if d[y] = 0 && d[y + 1] >= 1 then ret++
      if d[y] >= 1 && d[y + 1] = 0 then ret++
```

The final ret is the answer.

Comment: are they inside eachother?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I add the example, please read.

Comment: Please tell us why you think we will write the code for you when you cannot make an attempt at writing any code

Comment: @EdHeal I wrote O(N^2) pseudocode.

Answer (score 6):

There's an O(n log n)-time sweepline algorithm. Apply the following steps to compute the vertical perimeter of the shape. Transpose the input and apply them again to compute the horizontal perimeter.

For each rectangle, prepare a start event keyed by the left x-coordinate whose value is the y-interval, and a stop event keyed by the right x-coordinate whose value is the y-interval. Sort these events by x-coordinate and process them in order. At all times, we maintain a data structure capable of reporting the number of points at which the boundary intersects the sweepline. On the 2n - 1 intervals between event points, we add this number times the width of the interval to the perimeter.

The data structure we need supports the following operations in time O(log n).

```
insert(ymin, ymax) -- inserts the interval [ymin, ymax] into the data structure
delete(ymin, ymax) -- deletes the interval [ymin, ymax] from the data structure
perimeter() -- returns the perimeter of the 1D union of the contained intervals
```

Since the input coordinates are bounded integers, one possible implementation is via a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). (There's an extension to real inputs that involves sorting the y-coordinates of the input and remapping them to small integers.) Each segment has some associated data

```
struct {
    int covers_segment;
    bool covers_lower;
    int interior_perimeter;
    bool covers_upper;
};
```

whose scope is the union of segments descended from it that are present in the input intervals. (Note that a very long segment has no influence on the leafmost levels of the tree.)

The meaning of `covers_segment` is that it's the number of intervals that have this segment in their decomposition. The meaning of `covers_lower` is that it's true if one of the segments descended from this one with the same lower endpoint belongs to the decomposition of some interval. The meaning of `interior_perimeter` is the 1D perimeter of segments in scope (as described above). The meaning of `covers_upper` is akin to `covers_lower`, with the upper endpoint.

Here's an example.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

[---A---]
    [---B---] [-D-]
      [-C-]
```

Intervals are `A ([0, 4])` and `B ([2, 4], [4, 6])` and `C [3, 4] [4, 5]` and `D [7, 8] [8, 9]`.

```
               c_s  c_l  i_p  c_u
[0, 1]          0    F    0    F
  [0, 2]        0    F    0    F
[1, 2]          0    F    0    F
    [0, 4]      1    T    0    T
[2, 3]          0    F    0    F
  [2, 4]        1    T    1    T
[3, 4]          1    T    0    T
      [0, 8]    0    T    2    F
[4, 5]          1    T    0    T
  [4, 6]        1    T    1    T
[5, 6]          0    F    0    F
    [4, 8]      0    T    2    F
[6, 7]          0    F    0    F
  [6, 8]        0    F    1    F
[7, 8]          1    T    0    T
        [0, 9]  0    T    2    T
[8, 9]          1    T    0    T
```

To insert (delete) an interval, insert (delete) its constituent segments by incrementing (decrementing) `covers_segment`. Then, for all ancestors of the affected segments, recalculate the other fields as follows.

```
if s.covers_segment == 0:
    s.covers_lower = s.lower_child.covers_lower
    s.interior_perimeter =
        s.lower_child.interior_perimeter +
        (1 if s.lower_child.covers_upper != s.upper_child.covers_lower else 0) +
        s.upper_child.interior_perimeter
    s.covers_upper = s.upper_child.covers_upper
else:
    s.covers_lower = true
    s.interior_perimeter = 0
    s.covers_upper = true
```

To implement `perimeter`, return

```
(1 if root.covers_lower else 0) +
root.interior_perimeter +
(1 if root.covers_upper else 0)
```

where `root` is the root of the segment tree.

Answer (score 3):

This might help in some cases of your problem:

Consider that this,

```
 _______
|       |_
|         |
|        _|
|___    |
    |   |
    |___|
```

has the same perimeter as this:

```
 _________
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
|_________|
```

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the classic solition for this problem would be a sweep-line-based "boolean merge" algorithm, which in its original form builds the union of these rectangles, i.e. builds the polygonal boundary of the result. The algorithm can easily be modified to calculate the perimeter of the resultant boundary without physically building it.

On the other hand, sweep-line-based "boolean merge" can do this for arbitrary polygonal input. Given that in your case the input is much more restricted (and simplified) - just a bunch of isothetic rectangles - it is quite possible that a more lightweight and clever solution exists.

Note, BTW, that union of such rectangles might actually be a multi-connected polygon, i.e. an area with holes in it.